# MSE loss in tensorflow 2.0 mistakes y_true for a reduction key

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, mean-square-error

I am using a really simple neural network with the latest version of tensorflow 2.0, on a jupyter notebook running python 3.7.0.
The NN has Xip, a float as output, which I use as a parameter in my function MainGaussian_1_U, which approximates an image. When I try to compute the loss using MeanSquareError between the real image img and the approximation mk, I am given an error in which the loss function seems to take img as a reduction key. After searches, I still have no idea what this key is supposed to be, and can't find a way to debug my code:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

# Add the layers
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="relu"))

# The loss method
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
# The optimize
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
# This metrics is used to track the progress of the training loss during the training
train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')

def train_step(Data, img):
    MainGaussian_init(Data)
    for _ in range (5):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            Xip= model( (sizeh**-2 * np.ones((sizeh, sizeh))).reshape(-1, 49))
            MainGaussian_1_U ()
            print ("img=", img)
            loss= tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(img, mk)
            print ("loss=", loss)
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        print (gradients)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
        train_loss(loss)

train_step (TestFile, TestFile[4])
```

The error given is:

```
c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\losses\loss_reduction.py:67: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  if key not in cls.all():

...

ValueError: Invalid Reduction Key [[21.05224609 20.79420471 34.9659729  ... 48.09233093 68.83874512
  83.10766602]
 [20.93516541 17.0511322  39.00476074 ... 56.74258423 47.75274658
  98.57067871]
 [38.18562317 22.70791626 24.37176514 ... 64.9606781  47.65338135
  67.61506653]
 ...
 [85.76565552 79.45443726 73.64129639 ... 73.66456604 47.06422424
  49.44664001]
 [87.14616394 82.38183594 77.00856018 ... 66.21652222 71.32862854
  58.39285278]
 [36.74142456 37.27145386 34.52891541 ... 29.58699036 37.37667847
  30.25990295]].
```

This is my first question here on Stack Overflow: please let me know if I can make it any clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly create the "loss object", but never use it. Instead, your code tries to create a new "loss object" with the images as parameters (which doesn't work). Instead, you want to put the images into the already-created loss object. You just have to change this line

```
loss= tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(img, mk)
```

to

```
loss= loss_object(img, mk)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It now computes the loss!
However, when the gradients show up as [None, None, None, None, None, None] and it causes an error when I try to apply it to trainable variables; "ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:"

Does this have something to do with the same kind of error as the first one? If not is there something else that's basic and I don't understand?

Again, thanks for your initial answer!

Comment: Uh, now looking at your code, what is `mk`? I don't see it defined anywhere. You need to actually use the output of the model in the loss, otherwise no gradients can be computed. Also, all steps need to be differentiable (have gradients defined). You are calling a function `MainGaussian_1_U` that I don't know what it does (also `MainGaussianInit`). It might be best to post a separate question with all the relevant code for this specific problem.

Comment: This code is meant to decode a blurry image. MainGaussianInit Is there to pass informations about the Image and the blurr (such as their sizes etc). Then MainGaussian_1_U represents one iteration of the decoder. It updates various variables as well as the estimated image: mk. My goal is to learn the parameter Xip from the estimated blurr matrix (where for now is a placeholder `(sizeh**-2 * np.ones((sizeh, sizeh))).reshape(-1, 49)` ) as Xip is used at each iteration and changes a lot in the decoder's performance